# Why this line is not of valid Json format?

Tags: json

Why is the following line not a valid Json format? Thanks!

```
{u'FirstName': u'John', u'Title': u'Mr', u'LastName': u'Doe'}
```

Comment: Because it already is an object (or a `dict`, if python)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have 'u' before the name in a few places and you use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: Last time I checked, `{'key':'value'}` was valid JSON.

Comment: @cricket_007 on Json web site is link to validator which I've used and {'key':'value'} doesn't validate.

Comment: Hmm, well, it works in the Chrome Dev Console, but it does convert them to double quotes.